# Migration for tables already created Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have ASP.NET Project that have Entity Framework, it have its DbContext to map to their tables on DB.
Recently I added a model and perform a migration, but later I found that this project doesn't have any migrations, but have tables in DB.
So I created an initial migration with that new table, but is also including the other tables (because I had no previous migrations obliviously)

Since migrations are a requirement for this project and I cannot drop any table to start migration history from beginning, how can i safety perform a migration of my new table and keeping a right migration history?

I was thinking in to do something like this:

- Delete the InitialMigration file that I created via dotnet ef add
- Create a new InitialMigration with the current already created tables
  (not sure how to do that) and somehow mark it as migrated.
- Add the new model/table with another migration and update database.

Could you provide any help to achieve that?

Comment: You use source control, right?  You could back up your current code, roll back to the version just before you added the new table, create the initial migration from that code, and finally merge your current code into that and create another migration for the new table.

Comment: I just found this: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jan/13/Resetting-Entity-Framework-Migrations-to-a-clean-Slate